# Lightning Web Components, how to set lightning-input autocomplete="off"

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I have a lightning-input with type="search".
I am having trouble to set autocomplete="off" to be able to disable autocomplete functionality of modern browsers like Chrome.

Any help on this is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: sounds like your are looking to disable the browser "Autofill" functionality rather than an input field autocomplete ?

Comment: lightning-input does not have an autocomplete attribute (as far as the docuemntation goes)

Comment: @glls well, we can't ask every client to disable that functionality for all their users can we?

Comment: considering that this is a browser setting - they really dont have a choice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set autocomplete="off" in lightning form](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204520/how-to-set-autocomplete-off-in-lightning-form)

Answer (score 1):

To switch off browser autofill, try `html-autocomplete="nope"`
Chrome ignores `autocomplete="off"` but assigning a random string like `nope` works sometimes.

Alternatively, see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields) for disabling autocomplete. 
The [last section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Tools_for_Disabling_Autocompletion) describes `jquery.disableAutoFill` which could be another way of disabling autocomplete.