# lwc input-field autocomplete="off"

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield, autocomplete

I know that on [`lightning-input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) you can set `autocomplete="off"` to deactivate browser autofill feature. Now I am looking for something similar to this on `lightning-input-field`.

Has anyone found any workaround for this? Do I really have to rewrite all with `lightning-input`?

[image]

Currently i am using `record-edit-form` with `input-field`.

```
<div slot="modalContent" class="modalContent slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="ImpartnerMDF__FundsClaim__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Invoice_Payee_Name__c" required autocomplete="off"></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</div>
```

I know about this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204520/how-to-set-autocomplete-off-in-lightning-form) that seems to be related, but there are discussing aura component `aura:input` which really is not what I am using here, lwc component `lightning-input-field`. As far as I know the `autocomplete` attribute needs to be set on the html `input` tag, and from lwc shadow DOM perspective we are not able to dynamically query for this element via js.

I was thinking that maybe load js as static resources could bypass shadow DOM? -> Nope, even externally loaded script could not cross the shadow dom boundary for me.

Another approach I was thinking about would be to use `lightning-input` just for input, then have `lightning-input-field` with `display: none;` to which via js I will force the values.

Comment: Why don't you add your workaround as an answer? That way this question gets an answer and people can vote on it which gives a hint to future people that this works.

Comment: Will do, this question were closed as duplicate and got opened just recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, the last guess was the most successful. Use `lightnig-input` with `autocomplete="off"`, hide the `input-field`. Via `onchange` event, set the value from `lightning-input` to `input-field`.

Only bad thing on this solution is that you will lose the validation messages on the `input-field` which is hidden. But there is a workaround for this as well, something like displaying custom error messages.

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of autocomplete in lightning fields -

1- **Cache suggestions** - Use property **autocomplete="off"** in your input component to prevent these suggestions.

2- **Browser autofill** - ***Remove the "name" property** of the input field to restrict the identification by the browser form.* **Use custom dataset property for name : data-name="Email" in place of name="Email".** to access it in the change event use - ***const fieldName = event.target.dataset.name;***. The browser autofill algorithm looks for the matching name fields to give autocomplete suggestions.

Unfortunately, there is no provision from Salesforce to stop this. However, this workaround will resolve the issue.

ex-

HTML:

```
<lightning-input
    label="Email"
    type="email"
    value={record.Email}
    onchange={handleChange}
    data-name="Email"
    autocomplete="off">
</lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
 handleChange(event) {
   let fieldName = event.target.dataset.name
 }
```

Comment: Can you pls provide some code snippets?

Comment: updated with example @Damecek , hope it helps.

Comment: as I thought, in your answer you are using `ligntning-input` but the question was about `lightning-input-field` which is different component